# Laravel Logout functionality not working?

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

In laravel 5.7 Logout functionality not working when im going to click logout button it show me this error
    /var/www/html/orderManager/vendor/auth0/login/src/Auth0/Login/Auth0Service.php

```
$this->authApi = new Authentication($this->auth0Config['domain'], 
$this->auth0Config['client_id']);
```

"Undefined index: domain"

[image]

web.php

```
Route::get('logout', 'HomeController@logout');
```

HomeController.php

```
public function logout() {
        Auth::logout();
        Session::flush();
        return redirect('/login');
    }
```

Comment: Have you set `domain` in `config/laravel-auth0.php`?

Comment: Did you even try to read the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i remove this

```
"auth0/login": "~5.0"
```

from composer.json and `update composer` and its working..

Answer (score 0):

In case you are doing a custom logout yourself, you can change your logout method to look like this

```
public function logout() {
     auth()->logout();
     return redirect('/login');
}
```

Then remove the auth0 package and try running composer update